# Embedding form values in an ASP.Net MVC JavaScript URL.Action Call

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to pass parameters to an ASP.Net MVC controller from a URL.Action call in JavaScript.  I have seen others post things similar to this, but not the exact circumstance I have although I have tried to implement what those solutions were, they did not translate.

I have a button on a modal form that I want to call a method in the controller when it is clicked and the modal form is closed.

Here's the HTML for the button:

```
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default closing-modal" data-dismiss="modal">Done</button>
    </div>
```

here's the javaScript

```
$(document).on('click', '.closing-modal', function () {
    var datePickers = document.getElementsByClassName("datepicker");
    var times = document.getElementsByClassName("timeField");
    var myStartDate = datePickers[0].value; 
    var myEndDate = datePickers[1].value;
    var myStartTime = times[0].value;
    var myEndTime = times[1].value;

    window.location.href = '@Url.Action("ContractSelectedIndex", "ReviewTicket")';

});
```

and here's the receiving method in the controller:

```
    public ActionResult ContractSelectedIndex(string startDate, string startTime, string endDate, string endTime)
```

I have tried various ways to add a new {}, but because of the @ I can't find the right syntax.  This is what I have tried that makes the most sense to me (only first parameter for the sake of the example), but it does not like it.

```
    window.location.href = '@Url.Action("ContractSelectedIndex", "ReviewTicket", new { startDate: ' + myStartDate + ')' ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this if you prefer classic mvc  style

```
var url='@Url.Action("ContractSelectedIndex", "ReviewTicket")'
+ '/' + startDate + '/' + startTime + '/' + endDate + '/' +endTime;

window.location.href = url;
```

in this case your action should be

```
[Route("~/ReviewTicket/ContractSelectedIndex/{startDate}/{startTime}/{endDate}/{endTime}")]
public ActionResult ContractSelectedIndex(string startDate, string startTime, string endDate, string endTime)
```

or this

```
var url='@Url.Action("ContractSelectedIndex", "ReviewTicket")'
+ '?startDate=' + startDate + '&startTime=' + startTime + '&endDate=' + endDate + '&endTime=' + endTime;

window.location.href = url;
```

in this case you can use the action you have now

Comment: Thank you!  For the sake of anyone else who tries this, there is a syntax error (missing + in the last param) in solution #2 (which is the one I used)  Once I fixed it, it worked like a charm!